# android - Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]

Tags: android, google-api

I am totally new to android application development, I want to develop a sample map application using android studio

I followed the tutorial as such in http://android.rzeszow.net/?p=79 and the code is same

the emulator is GoogleAPI level 18

Once it ran and only + and - appeared on the map

Now in whichever emulator i try to run ( tried from google api level 13 to 18)

"Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]"

I have done the solutions given in various stack overflow pages, but nothg seemed to work

Please suggest a solution

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Remove the unnecessary `<uses-library>` element from your manifest. Clearly you have one, which is triggering this error. Maps V2 does not need such an element.

Comment: that worked!! but still map is not displayed, only + and - comes ( zoom in and zoom out icons)

Comment: @karthi: That's a separate issue. Make sure you have your `<meta-data>` element set up properly with your API key, make sure that you are checking for the Play Services Framework, make sure that you have the right permissions in your app, and make sure that the device or emulator has Internet access. There are plenty of questions and answers on StackOverflow for that issue that may provide other solutions.

Comment: Same problem here, but I need this library so i can't remove it